# Shiny: Removing record numbering from DataRenderTable

Tags: r, shiny

I have below code:

```
t_af_ts_outcomes <- datatable( data     = cars
                             , options  = list( bFilter       = 0
                                              , bLengthChange = 0
                                              , paging        = F
                                              , info          = F
                                              )

                             )

output$v_af_ts_outcomes <- renderDataTable( t_af_ts_outcomes )
```

And it gives below output:
[image]

Is there anyway I can remove the row numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set argument `rownames = FALSE` inside `datatable()` function.